# Java WebService

Tags: java, asp.net, .net, web-services

What is the Java equivalent to Script service (like web service but with JSON instead of XML) in the .net world?

I am looking for a way of creating and invoiking web services using java. I prefer to find a way that will allow me define a method that will act as web service. I don't like the solutions of "dedicated jsp or servlet" for the specific request.

Is there any wat of doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of frameworks that help you to do this. I personally prefer Spring. 
But you can just search for "Java based RESTful web services frameworks". Here is a list of such framework from Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_service_frameworks

Enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

You can use libraries like [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) or [RESTeasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy) for the implementation of web services. For the consumers, you can use the built in classes of the same libraries or, if you prefer, can use [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html)

I personally prefer using Jersey + HttpClient combination :)

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer RESTful services which fits for your need of "**I prefer to find a way that will allow me define a method that will act as web service.**" Just with REST annotations You can set a method as a Service.

Code Snippet simple REST

@Path("/rest")
public Class MyFirstService
{

```
//Method without Path parameters
@GET
@Path("/name")
@Produces("application/json")
public String getMyName()
{
    return "My Name:";
}

//Method with Path parameters
@GET
@Path("/name/{id}")
@Produces("application/json")
public String getMyName(@Pathparam("id")String Id)
{
    if(Id.equals("1")
         return "My Name:";
    else
         return "None";
}
```

}

RESTful Services give four major Services as - 
GET
PUT
POST
DELETE

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend JEE6, especially if your focus is going to be on REST based services. Glassfish 3 and JBoss 7 are neck and neck now with their implementation, either would be a good choice (though JBoss is my personal preference). With the JAX-RS and JAS-WS specifications you simply annotate your classes and they become web service capable:

Make your bean a SOAP based web service:

```
@WebService
public class AccountImpl {

    // You can explicitly mark the methods you want to make available in your WSDL
    @WebMethod
    public BigDecimal getBalance() {}
}
```

Make your bean a REST based web service:

```
@Path("/rs/account")
public class AccountImpl {

    @GET
    @Path("/balance")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public BigDecimal getBalance() {}
}
```

The code snippet is just an example. You can find more resources online for learning JAX-RS and JAX-WS. Here are a few links:

- [RESTEasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy)
- [Jersey](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/Jersey/Main)
- [JAX-WS Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jax_ws_2/)

*Note: I included information about JAX-WS for reference only. You indicated you wanted to build JSON services, which implies REST*